# NSNumberFormatter list of supported currencies

Tags: ios, internationalization

Looks like NSNumberFormatter support very limited count of currencies, for example it can't return symbol for @"UAH". Where i can found a list of supported currencies?

Comment: What did you try ? `UAH` is listed in the array returned by `[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes]` ...

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for the `₴` symbol.

Comment: If you set the number formatter's locale to a Ukranian locale, you will get the `₴` symbol instead of `UAH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to print the supported currencies.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
for (NSString *code in [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes]) {
NSLog(@"%@ : %@", code, [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:code]);
}
```

See if the out put is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *locales = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
NSLocale *locale = nil;

for (NSString *local in locales) {

    locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:local];

    NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
    NSString *country = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
    NSString *currencyCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    NSString *currencyDescription = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:currencyCode];


    if (countryCode != nil) {
        NSLog(@"\n Country: %@ \n CountryCode: %@ \n Currency Code: %@ \n Currency Name: %@",country,countryCode,currencyCode,currencyDescription);
    }
}
```